# Create a pom.xml file outside any project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I was thinking about a question : is it possible to create an "admin" pom.xml file outside any project on my GitLab server and, when I am in a new project, define it as a parent pom.xml ? 
It could help me with CI/CD because I will define the server's configuration and the distribution management for example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you have a "company parent POM" for that. It is a separate project that you build with your build server and then reference as a parent POM from everywhere. It contains plugin versions, distribution management, properties etc.

Comment: thank you for your comment !  But is it compulsory to place it in a separate project ? Or could we use it just as a file (it is maybe not recommanded with maven policy).

Comment: Every POM must have project.